# Android GridView ArrayAdapter Images switching on scroll with Volley

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, android-volley

So I have an ArrayAdapter for a gridview that populates a NetworkImageView after getting the location of the image from a StringRequest. When I scroll through the grid the image for each item switches several times before settling on the correct image.

I suspect the problem lies in that the images are being populated by an imageLoader after a StringRequest and the grid items are being reused, however I thought that the NetworkImageView cancelled previous requests of images and that would prevent this behaviour.
Below is the code that I am using - any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridrowlayout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        assert view != null;
        holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.networkImageView = (MNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    MyObject myObject = myObjects.get(position);
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = getUrl(myObject);
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.networkImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.loading);
    holder.networkImageView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.no_image_available);
    holder.textView.setText(myObject.getName() + "\n " + myObject.getYear());
    if (MyApplication.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable()) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String json) {
                try {
                    Resp resp = gson.fromJson(json, Resp.class);
                    String tbUrl = resp.getPoster();
                    holder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(tbUrl, imageLoader);
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    Log.i(ImageAdapter.TAG, "status failed");
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, ImageAdapter.TAG);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: change your design pattern, first download for example 10 image urls and then call notifydatasetchanged(). you load by making two requests and i think this is not good idea for gridview you must change it a bit so that user experience one loading delay.